# bridge0: received packet on bond0 with own address as source address

Tags: networking, bridge, bonding

I have created a bond using netplan (ubuntu 18.04) which shows the same MAC address for the two member physical NICs and the bond itself. I configured a bridge on top of that, for use with KVM/Qemu VMs.

```
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master 
   bond0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
   link/ether 2a:5b:a6:18:e7:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master 
   bond0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
   link/ether 2a:5b:a6:18:e7:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: bridge0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state 
   UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
   link/ether 6e:2b:1c:0e:af:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue 
   master bridge0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
   link/ether 2a:5b:a6:18:e7:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

All looks OK and seems to work, but I'm getting tons of these errors in the log:

```
kernel: bridge0: received packet on bond0 with own address as source 
address (addr:6e:2b:1c:0e:af:6e, vlan:0)
```

My netplan config:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
  eno1:
    match:
      macaddress: 74:46:a0:fe:ee:7c
  eno2:
    match:
      macaddress: 74:46:a0:fe:ee:7d
bonds:
  bond0:
    interfaces: [eno1, eno2]
bridges:
  bridge0:
    interfaces: [bond0]
    dhcp4: false
    addresses: [172.16.62.200/24]
    gateway4: 172.16.62.1
```

What is going wrong here? Why the errors?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

OK just needed to do more experimenting.  Adding an explicit bond mode sorted it out. I went for:

```
  bond0:
    interfaces: [eno1, eno2]
    parameters:
      mode: balance-tlb
```

No more errors.

Actually I think the issue was that a host reboot is required between changes. I was just doing a "netplan apply".